# jQuery dialog capture event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

i am quite new to jquery but getting there with the help of forums like this. what is the correct way to use dialog in relation to my code? for example, at the moment i am just alerting the celdiv to the screen but i would like to use dialog to show result. can someone show how to use my alert code to pass to dialog?. thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function procMe(celDiv,id) {
        $(celDiv).click(function () 

            {
            alert(this.innerHTML + " " + id); 
            }
        )}; 
</script>
```

Comment: what do you exaclty want it to know? a good way for starting is [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)`

Comment: yeh thanks for tip. basically when i use dialog i call from class or # such as: $("#paragraph").dialog({ etc what i am not seeing is what the selector should be to call dialog based on my code? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using dialog you should have a container  in your html like this:

```
<div id="dialogbox">Some dummy text here</div>
```

and write this kind of script:

```
<script>
function procMe(celDiv,id) {
        $(celDiv).click(function () 

            {
            var me = this;
            $("#dialogbox").html(me.innerHTML + " " + id);
            $("#dialogbox").dialog();        
            }
        )}; 
</script>
```

This code show up the same content of your alert inside a Jquery UI Dialog instead of the classic alert box

If I missed the point please let us know more details ;)

Comment: excellent. just one question. why the dummy div? is that just created for the #dialogbox? many thanks

Comment: actually, is not needed, sorry :D but you do need the div (even if empty)

Answer (score 0):

try using jQuery plugin for showing alerts or confirms.

you can use 
http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

or

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/12/better-confirm-box-jquery-css3/

i have used both.. and happy with their features.

Comment: @rifky. they are good but would like to keep the overall theme of the site the same. thanks

Comment: try using the second one.. you can get a idea from the normal version of the second plugin jquery.

Comment: any how you can alter the CSS to set the theme according to your site.

Comment: @ rifky. sorry i do not understand your comment.

Comment: @bollo. i mean you can edit the plugin's css to match your site theme. the second plugin in my answer is more user freindly in readability. you can download a non minified version so that you can alter the CSS according to your theme.

Comment: i would still like to try and understand the way dialog handles events. i have read the docs at the site but from what i can see it just highlights class and div selectors. hence my post. thanks